# Get real Visitors IP in Apache behind Nginx reverse proxy dont work

Tags: apache, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

After 5 hours trying to solve the problem and read any tutorial i have found, i ask here for help.

I have an `Nginx Reverse Proxy` Server that points to my `Apache` Web Server, but on `Apache` i got just the `IP address` from `Nginx reverse proxy` server not visitors ip.

**My nginx proxy file:** `/etc/nginx/sites-available/proxy.conf`

```
proxy_pass http://MYIPADDRESS;
proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
```

On Apache i have added to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file:

```
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
```

and replaced

```
LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

with

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %{X-Forwarded-For}i" combined
```

`a2enmod remoteip` also enabled

Also in Nginx `/var/log/nginx/access.log` file i got always just `localhost` IP like:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jan/2020:23:53:07 +0800] "GET...
```

Also have tried to add to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For
```

If i run on my Webserver now an PHP Script in Browser:

```
<?php

echo 'User IP - '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

?>
```

I just got the Reverse Proxy Servers IP and its the same for whole server.

Both Servers OS are Debian 9, any one an idea? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure you installed and enabled [mod_remoteip](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_remoteip.html) apache module.

I use the following configuration on my server.

In httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so

RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
RemoteIPInternalProxy 127.0.0.1
```

In nginx site configuration file:

```
proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Comment: What this line mean? `proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;` if i use your code i got my direct IP access blocked error

Comment: This set X-Forwarded-Prodo HTTP header to 'http' or 'https' depending on visitor protocol.

Comment: Okay if i just use your `httpd.conf` content and replace `127.0.0.1` with my Proxy IP it comes as user IP `127.0.0.1`, i think its correct but nginx dont log the Users IP because in my `/var/log/nginx/access.log` its also for every visitor `127.0.0.1` as IP correct? if yes how can i solve this?

Comment: Maybe with `ngx_http_realip_module`?

Comment: No, `ngx_http_realip_module` needed when you use nginx besides some other (maybe also nginx) reverse proxy or load balancing server.

Comment: I am using your answer in a Docker context and by inspecting the network and taking the IP address of the NGINX server I was able to get the real outside IP logged in Apache. Thank you.